# csv file name match with dict keys

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I encounter a problem:

```
data={'a':'1-2-3','b':'3-4-5','c':'','d':'3--3'}
for i in data.values():
    df=pandas.DataFrame(i.split('-'))
    df.to_csv('a.csv')
```

I want get four csv file:

```
a.csv
   0
0  1
1  2
2  3

b.csv
   0
0  3
1  4
2  5

c.csv

d.csv
   0
0  3
1   
2  3
```

I try use format and other meathod, but it can't work.Thanks a lot

Comment: `for key, val in data.items(): df.to_csv(key + '.csv')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data.items() will work in both python2 and python3 as well. You can see the script below which wrote in python2.

```
>>> for k,v in data.items():
...     df = pandas.DataFrame(v.split('-'))
...     df.to_csv(k + '.csv')
...
>>> import os
>>> [ i for i in os.listdir('.') if i.endswith('.csv')]
['a.csv', 'b.csv', 'c.csv', 'd.csv']
```